# How to change the default FAB image in scrolling activty

Tags: android

I am trying to learn to work on scrolling activity (android studio) but I am unable to change the default Fab Icon provided by the activity itself. Can someone please provide some guidance about changing the Fab icon to another icon image?

(*In short*: How to change "mail" Icon to "+" icon)

Comment: in your xml change src drawable: android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"

Comment: Post your layout XML where you have created the FAB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your xml change src drawable:

```
android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
```

to your desirable icon.

Comment: Thanks bud,it was helpful but as a starter in scrolling activity it took time to locate XML,but I am sure this was so helpful

Comment: @justDroid Can you tell me.. where are all of the `desirable icons` located?    How do you know what else is available besides `@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email` ??  Under the sample application, I see a `res` folder (resources?) and under that I see a `drawable` folder, but its empty.  Where is `@android:drawable/...` ?

Answer (score 3):

Plus Icon Image add into Drawble folder 
Here is image.

[image: Plus icon add in drawable]

Write in your xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:background="#C2185B"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add" />
```

Answer (score 2):

change your `android:src="@android:drawable/your_image.png"`
where your_image is your image in drawable folder

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to find the solution a easyone for this simple problem,in .java(Scrolling activity)you will be able to locate

> ***fab***,Right click it -->Go to--> Declaration-->The page you land is the page you need to edit for changing the Fab icon.

Upload the fab icon Image you have in

> *android:src="@drawable/*****"*.

and the fab icon will be changed

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that `ic_input_add` is found in the R.drawable reference at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html#ic_input_add

In Android Studio 3.3.2 in a new Kotlin program, this setting is found in the `activity_main.xml` file. The default FloatingActionButton settings are:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>
```

The last line of this code block is being changed to:
`app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"/>`

You will notice a preview of the drawable image next to the line number if you are editing in Android Studio 3.3.2. Click this image and you can open the resource. Here you will see a full view of the image and the path to the image. In my case it's in the `~\plugins\android\lib\layoutlib\data\res\drawable-ldpi` directory. It may be different for you, but easy enough to determine from there. Other compatible drawables are found there as well.

---

Here is a list of other drawables from the reference (be sure to check the reference as it may change):

> ic_btn_speak_now
>
> ic_delete
>
> ic_dialog_alert
>
> ic_dialog_dialer
>
> ic_dialog_email
>
> ic_dialog_info
>
> ic_dialog_map
>
> ic_input_add
>
> ic_input_delete
>
> ic_input_get
>
> ic_lock_idle_alarm
>
> ic_lock_idle_charging
>
> ic_lock_idle_lock
>
> ic_lock_idle_low_battery
>
> ic_lock_lock
>
> ic_lock_power_off
>
> ic_lock_silent_mode
>
> ic_lock_silent_mode_off
>
> ic_media_ff
>
> ic_media_next
>
> ic_media_pause
>
> ic_media_play
>
> ic_media_previous
>
> ic_media_rew
>
> ic_menu_add
>
> ic_menu_agenda
>
> ic_menu_always_landscape_portrait
>
> ic_menu_call
>
> ic_menu_camera
>
> ic_menu_close_clear_cancel
>
> ic_menu_compass
>
> ic_menu_crop
>
> ic_menu_day
>
> ic_menu_delete
>
> ic_menu_directions
>
> ic_menu_edit
>
> ic_menu_gallery
>
> ic_menu_help
>
> ic_menu_info_details
>
> ic_menu_manage
>
> ic_menu_mapmode
>
> ic_menu_month
>
> ic_menu_more
>
> ic_menu_my_calendar
>
> ic_menu_mylocation
>
> ic_menu_myplaces
>
> ic_menu_preferences
>
> ic_menu_recent_history
>
> ic_menu_report_image
>
> ic_menu_revert
>
> ic_menu_rotate
>
> ic_menu_save
>
> ic_menu_search
>
> ic_menu_send
>
> ic_menu_set_as
>
> ic_menu_share
>
> ic_menu_slideshow
>
> ic_menu_sort_alphabetically
>
> ic_menu_sort_by_size
>
> ic_menu_today
>
> ic_menu_upload
>
> ic_menu_upload_you_tube
>
> ic_menu_view
>
> ic_menu_week
>
> ic_menu_zoom
>
> ic_notification_clear_all
>
> ic_notification_overlay
>
> ic_partial_secure
>
> ic_popup_disk_full
>
> ic_popup_reminder
>
> ic_popup_sync
>
> ic_search_category_default
>
> ic_secure

Answer (score 0):

Change the keyword as given below will show you the add button.

```
app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
```